# How to implement a complex application in ROS

Tags: control, ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everybody!

I managed to get the navigation and arm_navigation stack running on my robot system (a custom system built at my university). So, I know how to send navigation goals to a mobile base and an arm. Now, I want to realize a more complex applikation, e.g. find objects in a room, move the base to them and grasp them.

I wonder what is the recommended way in ROS to implement a control structure for the application?
I'm thinking about implementing a state machine in one node that controlles the others, or is there a better way? How is it done on pr2?

Thanks for your help!
kind regards,
Benny

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9975/how-to-implement-a-complex-application-in-ros/) by [BennyRos](https://answers.ros.org/users/546/bennyros/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2011-05-17

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You could have a look at [SMACH](http://www.ros.org/wiki/executive_smach).

---

Originally posted by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) with karma: 11816 on 2011-05-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [BennyRos](https://answers.ros.org/users/546/bennyros/) on 2011-05-17**:
Thanks for your answer! SMACH looks interesting. I'll try it. Has anybody experiences with other approaches? I use ROS within a student project and it would be nice if I could compare several approaches.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Some of the other approaches available in ROS:

- http://www.ros.org/wiki/cram_pl
- http://www.ros.org/wiki/behavior_engine
- http://www.ros.org/wiki/executive_trex

---

Originally posted by [bhaskara](https://answers.ros.org/users/95/bhaskara/) with karma: 1479 on 2011-05-18

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [BennyRos](https://answers.ros.org/users/546/bennyros/) on 2011-05-18**:
Thank for your help, bhaskara! I'll have a look at these approaches.